# Facebook javascript sdk integration not working properly

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

I am developing a web app in which I wan't to import contacts from from facebook..

I have tried several times to include javascript for faceboook but it didn't worked for me...

Oauth dialog comes reporting an error ...

And same facebook app I tried to access on facebook shows auth dialog to access permission and It works fine ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Solved.

Just configuration problem.

Url for website was not proper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your source code, if you expect any reasonable answer.